# Get cursor position relative to element, ignoring children

Tags: javascript, event-listener, cursor-position

I'm trying to get the position of my cursor ignoring all other elements on my page (including those with event listeners of their own).

I know you can get the position of the cursor like this:

```
const parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax").forEach((parallax) => {
   document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      let x = e.offsetX - parallax.innerWidth / 2;
      let y = e.offsetY - parallax.innerHeight / 2;
   });
});
```

The above will get the mouse cursor position relative to the center of the target element.

How ever, it will also get the cursor position relative to any of the target's *children*, which isn't what I want. I'd like it to ignore all children, siblings and anything that may be in the way of the event trigger. (sort of like a transparent effect, similar to how an element set to `pointer-events: none` in css would react)

Comment: I've seen that answer before. I'm trying to make it so that the target's children are *invisible* to the event listener, not stop completely if it's over the children.

Comment: It's a little unclear what your current snippet is doing (what's `thumb`?) If you just use `currentTarget` in place of `target` when referencing the hovered element you should be able to achieve your "transparent" child elements.

Comment: that's a typo. `thumb` is meant to be `target`. For some reason, I cant edit my post

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post, I've edited it @DBS
The `.parallax` element has a child. But I dont want the child to interfere with the event listener. So, if the mouse ever hovers over `.parallax`'s child, the event listener will ignore it and behave as if it isnt there. Hope that clears things up.